# LINQ query always return Null

Tags: linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I am new in LINQ and I have a problem.

I have two tables in two different dbContext(userContext and mailContext). I want to select a part of data from UserAccount table, after I add this data to UserMail table. UserAccount table have lots of columns and UserMail tables have 4 columns (CreatedDate, UserAccountId, UserType, ItemCount)

The selection code:

```
 var selectedUsers = _userContext.UserAccount
        .Where(x=>x.Created == new DateTime(2021, 02, 17))
        .Select(x => new UserMail()
        {
            CreatedDate = x.Created,
            UserAccountId = x.AccountId,
            UserType = x.UserType,
            ItemCount = (int?)x.ItemCount,
        }).ToList();
```

The query return null, The count of selectedUsers=0. I check from SQL, some data exits, am I miss a point in the query?

Actually, I need the sum of ItemCount grouped by AccountId and CreatedDate but first of all, I want to get the result of this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you can't satisfy the `where` condition since highly likely *hours/minutes/seconds* parts are not equal each other. What about the following?

```
var selectedUsers = _userContext.UserAccount
        .Where(x=>x.Created.Date == new DateTime(2021, 02, 17).Date)
        // new DateTime(2021, 02, 17) could be used simply but the default
        // behavior may be changed in future.
        .Select(x => new UserMail()
        {
            CreatedDate = x.Created,
            UserAccountId = x.AccountId,
            UserType = x.UserType,
            ItemCount = (int?)x.ItemCount,
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it's not working. When I remove the where clause, it is working. In the database the date format is 2021-02-17 11:30:35.113. How can I convert this 2021-02-17 in where clause?

Comment: The output of `_userContext.UserAccount[0].Created` is 2021-01-15 16:23:18.210

Comment: oov, I am so sorry, I did'nt see the .Date in both side of the equation. Thanks again, it works.